# DRUPAL и вставка php кода в модули

Tags: php, drupal

Правлю стандартный модуль входа на друпале (чтобы вставить js кнопку появления логин меню.). Получилась такая конструкция:

```
function user_block_view($delta = '') {
  global $user;

  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'login':
      // For usability's sake, avoid showing two login forms on one page.
      if (!$user->uid && !(arg(0) == 'user' && !is_numeric(arg(1)))) {



        $block['subject'] = t('User login');
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');


      }



    echo '<div id="loginform" ><span onclick="loginblock ();">ENTER</span></div>';



return $block;
```

По неизвестной причине он выводит кнопку в начале страницы, отрезая половину хеда, который оказывается в итоге в теле страницы. Понимаю, тупой вопрос, но в Drupal, как и в php я оч недавно..